# Can data be migrated from Stack Overflow for Teams to Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-overflow-enterprise

Is it possible to migrate data from Stack Overflow for Teams to Stack Overflow Enterprise?  Can this be triggered entirely by the user or does it require help from Stack Overflow people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to migrate the data from Stack Overflow for Teams to Stack Overflow Enterprise.

Setting up Enterprise is not a self-service endeavor and migrating that data will be done by the Stack Overflow team as part of your setup.

Not totally related, but also potentially relevant -- as a SO for Teams admin, you can download Teams data from the admin dashboard in JSON format at any time.

Comment: I don't see any option to download the data anywhere? Is this feature still available or do I need to enter my billing information to access it ?